# VSTS 2010 version issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have tried hard to find something to learn VSTS 2010 version comparisons, like Ultimate version, professional version, etc. Any brief document describes their functional differences from developer perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This table from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products#compareTable) seems like a good start. The [Visual Studio Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) has much the same information, presented differently.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products ?